# Python: Non-Uniform Array using List Comprehension

Tags: python, arrays, list, syntax, list-comprehension

I would like to initialize a 2D array using list comprehension with variable size sub-arrays.  All the values in the array should be random.

See the example below - note that each number in `dim` refers to the length of the sub-arrays.

```
dim = [1,3,1] -> this would make the array:
[[.143],
[.534], [.732], [.741],
[.989]]
```

So far I have tried the following:

```
arr = [[random.random() for b in range(b)] for a in range(len(dim))]]
```

However I am recieving the error `NameError: name 'b' is not defined`.  Am I missing something easy?  I could obviously use use list appending and conventional for loops, but I feel like there is a more python-y way of doing this!

Comment: `for b in range(b)` what do you expect that to do? don't you mean `in range(a)`?

Comment: also, `for a in range(len(nnDim))` is not doing what you want (whatever nnDim is). You probably simply want `for a in dim`

Comment: finally, give `a` a significant name, and use `_` instead of `b` to indicate that the variable is not used: `[[random.random() for _ in range(size)] for size in dim]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a very simple issue - the correct syntax is:

`arr = [[random.random() for b in range(dim[a])] for a in range(len(dim))]`